# Certificate error on Symbian OS

Tags: certificate, jks

Please help me.
I am using `.jks` certificate for signing my application in Eclipse and my application is working for Series 40 and Asha devices like Asha 501, 503, and Nokia C3.
However, it is not installing on Symbian OS Devices like Nokia C5, 5230. I am getting an error: `"Certificate error, Contact application supplier"`.
I have checked the certificate validity and other info which is ok and working.
My certificate is authorized by VeriSign.

I have tried the following on the Nokia 5230 device:

1. Tried to installed build with current date and time,old date and time.
2. Changed application setting to `Online certificate check= OFF` and `Software installation setting= Install all`.
3. I also removed the MIDlet-Certificate-1-3 from the Jad file, but that still didn't work.
   Please help me here to track the exact issue why this happening.

Please find the below details of my Jad file

```
MIDlet-1: Hungama,/icon.png,CHungama
MIDlet-Certificate-1-1: MIIFqzCCBJOgAwIBAgIQDqYSVfGoS9xSXmO8ZXWMQTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBtDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWduLCBJbmMuMR8wHQYDVQQLExZWZXJpU2lnbiBUcnVzdCBOZXR3b3JrMTswOQYDVQQLEzJUZXJtcyBvZiB1c2UgYXQgaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmVyaXNpZ24uY29tL3JwYSAoYykxMDEuMCwGA1UEAxMlVmVyaVNpZ24gQ2xhc3MgMyBDb2RlIFNpZ25pbmcgMjAxMCBDQTAeFw0xNDEyMDIwMDAwMDBaFw0xNTEyMjcyMzU5NTlaMIHcMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJTjEUMBIGA1UECBMLTWFoYXJhc2h0cmExDzANBgNVBAcTBk11bWJhaTE2MDQGA1UEChQtSHVuZ2FtYSBkaWdpdGFsIG1lZGlhIGVudGVydGFpbm1lbnQgUHZ0ICBMdGQuMTYwNAYDVQQLFC1IdW5nYW1hIGRpZ2l0YWwgbWVkaWEgZW50ZXJ0YWlubWVudCBQdnQgIEx0ZC4xNjA0BgNVBAMULUh1bmdhbWEgZGlnaXRhbCBtZWRpYSBlbnRlcnRhaW5tZW50IFB2dCAgTHRkLjCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMKHXpHsmQ+fWnNFzQELYthMM2Xv9/z+E8DDYUvQVEd6CQ/Wn9NCG+USyqalcoKK7t0ImMdLkui29ncJOmZjBDmKzmL1+CJArBu1xS5ZQWEUVxzkwRujQy/mog00aGWG93ARjBoAzM6vlBg9+s6+x9CibR3U3SaJ+elRuHFJKV//+f6mcTcQu2EF4S58nDcJ8th2bc/48Uu10rLu5q1loRA2jCcaCRswcNSDiHnKicodBNq8wjeyx4AD3y/zq5yO7T6Pg69oc1T7dXTaOr5DhrYZJln52UuRs2WXQkaggtkrSoz91/eHFY15Xr6Ufuu8w9q3EPw4jfkCO00Y8twr66cCAwEAAaOCAY0wggGJMAkGA1UdEwQCMAAwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgeAMCsGA1UdHwQkMCIwIKAeoByGGmh0dHA6Ly9zZi5zeW1jYi5jb20vc2YuY3JsMGYGA1UdIARfMF0wWwYLYIZIAYb4RQEHFwMwTDAjBggrBgEFBQcCARYXaHR0cHM6Ly9kLnN5bWNiLmNvbS9jcHMwJQYIKwYBBQUHAgIwGQwXaHR0cHM6Ly9kLnN5bWNiLmNvbS9ycGEwEwYDVR0lBAwwCgYIKwYBBQUHAwMwVwYIKwYBBQUHAQEESzBJMB8GCCsGAQUFBzABhhNodHRwOi8vc2Yuc3ltY2QuY29tMCYGCCsGAQUFBzAChhpodHRwOi8vc2Yuc3ltY2IuY29tL3NmLmNydDAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBTPmanqeyb0S8mOj9fwBSbv49KnnTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUGpv9u2zSxdWxdwdpvpuPH90Jt6wwEQYJYIZIAYb4QgEBBAQDAgQQMBYGCisGAQQBgjcCARsECDAGAQEAAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQDihMuTa20A0Fk9JvUve7B9z4pOr8PNIyNS4RfEKEPl9cPsWEvFSGlcPLqKKqrys6TBxjc8e6EePxitAzjdAXEWH1+gCXxB6IeEAmKrIWc5PxTkSCZ6joN7j/50PZn5eSnX20nDmRfPbIhXh0xt3+ihJ7T6FyAiH0PkjplH9DjWYOwzHwJjPY1pQK37vj2k3dHgrCwX31t9QXJprMErT+8zLnWdCvnx65bohpZb0unqxXJ7FbM5hRU3bTHjADCu8LO+TFZ8SWQmtKBDp78pcY2YTS+nRBH5gPquL5OahQ2iPr+1EC2T6wCZ3NWgO1OsV2v7v51cEdUCDC/vx4qpm42K
MIDlet-Certificate-1-2: MIIGCjCCBPKgAwIBAgIQUgDlqiVW/BqG7ZbJ1EszxzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCByjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWduLCBJbmMuMR8wHQYDVQQLExZWZXJpU2lnbiBUcnVzdCBOZXR3b3JrMTowOAYDVQQLEzEoYykgMjAwNiBWZXJpU2lnbiwgSW5jLiAtIEZvciBhdXRob3JpemVkIHVzZSBvbmx5MUUwQwYDVQQDEzxWZXJpU2lnbiBDbGFzcyAzIFB1YmxpYyBQcmltYXJ5IENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5IC0gRzUwHhcNMTAwMjA4MDAwMDAwWhcNMjAwMjA3MjM1OTU5WjCBtDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWduLCBJbmMuMR8wHQYDVQQLExZWZXJpU2lnbiBUcnVzdCBOZXR3b3JrMTswOQYDVQQLEzJUZXJtcyBvZiB1c2UgYXQgaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmVyaXNpZ24uY29tL3JwYSAoYykxMDEuMCwGA1UEAxMlVmVyaVNpZ24gQ2xhc3MgMyBDb2RlIFNpZ25pbmcgMjAxMCBDQTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAPUjS16l14q7MunUV/fv5Mcmfq0ZmP6onX2U9jZrENd1gTB/BGh/yyt1Hs0dCIzfaZSnN6Oce4DgmeHuN01fzjsU7obU0PUnNbwlCzinjGOdF6MIpauw+81qYoJM1SHaG9nx44Q7iipPhVuQAU/Jp3YQfycDfL6ufn3B3fkFvBtInGnnwKQ8PEEAPt+W5cXklHHWVQHHACZKQDy1oSapDKdtgI6QJXvPvz8c6y+W+uWHd8a1VrJ6O1QwUxvfYjT/HtH0WpMoheVMF05+W/2kk5l/383vpHXv7xX2R+f4GXLYLjQaprSnTH69u08MPVfxMNamNo7WgHbXGS6lzX40LYkCAwEAAaOCAf4wggH6MBIGA1UdEwEB/wQIMAYBAf8CAQAwcAYDVR0gBGkwZzBlBgtghkgBhvhFAQcXAzBWMCgGCCsGAQUFBwIBFhxodHRwczovL3d3dy52ZXJpc2lnbi5jb20vY3BzMCoGCCsGAQUFBwICMB4aHGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnZlcmlzaWduLmNvbS9ycGEwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMG0GCCsGAQUFBwEMBGEwX6FdoFswWTBXMFUWCWltYWdlL2dpZjAhMB8wBwYFKw4DAhoEFI/l0xqGrI2Oa8PPgGrUSBgsexkuMCUWI2h0dHA6Ly9sb2dvLnZlcmlzaWduLmNvbS92c2xvZ28uZ2lmMDQGA1UdHwQtMCswKaAnoCWGI2h0dHA6Ly9jcmwudmVyaXNpZ24uY29tL3BjYTMtZzUuY3JsMDQGCCsGAQUFBwEBBCgwJjAkBggrBgEFBQcwAYYYaHR0cDovL29jc3AudmVyaXNpZ24uY29tMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMCBggrBgEFBQcDAzAoBgNVHREEITAfpB0wGzEZMBcGA1UEAxMQVmVyaVNpZ25NUEtJLTItODAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUz5mp6nsm9EvJjo/X8AUm7+PSp50wHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUf9Nlp8Ld7LvwMAnzQzn6Aq8zMTMwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAFYi5jSkxGHLSLkBrVaoZA/ZjJHEu8wM5a16oCJ/30c4Si1s0X9xGnzscKmx8E/kDwxT+hVe/nSYSSSFgSYckRRHsExjjLuhNNTGRegNhSZzA9CpjGRt3HGS5kUFYBVZUTn8WBRr/tSk7XlrCAxBcuc3IgYJviPpP0SaHulhncyxkFz8PdKNrEI9ZTbUtD1AKI+bEM8jJsxLIMuQH12MTDTKPNjlN9ZvpSC9NOsm2a4N58Wa96G0IZEzb4boWLslfHQOWP51G2M/zjF8m48blp7FU3aEW5ytkfqs7ZO6XcghU8KCU2OvEg1QhxEbPVRSloosnD2SGgiaBS7Hk6VIkdM=
MIDlet-Certificate-1-3: MIIE0zCCA7ugAwIBAgIQGNrRniZ96LtKIVjNzGs7SjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCByjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWduLCBJbmMuMR8wHQYDVQQLExZWZXJpU2lnbiBUcnVzdCBOZXR3b3JrMTowOAYDVQQLEzEoYykgMjAwNiBWZXJpU2lnbiwgSW5jLiAtIEZvciBhdXRob3JpemVkIHVzZSBvbmx5MUUwQwYDVQQDEzxWZXJpU2lnbiBDbGFzcyAzIFB1YmxpYyBQcmltYXJ5IENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5IC0gRzUwHhcNMDYxMTA4MDAwMDAwWhcNMzYwNzE2MjM1OTU5WjCByjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWduLCBJbmMuMR8wHQYDVQQLExZWZXJpU2lnbiBUcnVzdCBOZXR3b3JrMTowOAYDVQQLEzEoYykgMjAwNiBWZXJpU2lnbiwgSW5jLiAtIEZvciBhdXRob3JpemVkIHVzZSBvbmx5MUUwQwYDVQQDEzxWZXJpU2lnbiBDbGFzcyAzIFB1YmxpYyBQcmltYXJ5IENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5IC0gRzUwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCvJAgIKXo1nmAMqudLO07cfLw8RRy7K+D+KQL5VwijZIUVJ/XxrcgxiV0i6CqqpkKzj/i5Vbext0uz/o9+B1fs70PbZmIVYc9gDaTY3vjgw2IIPVQT60nKWVSFJuUrjxuf6/WhkcIzSdhDY2pSS9KP6HBRTdGJaXvHcPaz3BJ023tdS1bTlr8Vd6Gw9KIl8q8ckmcY5fQGBO+QueQA5N06tRn/Arr0PO7gi+s3i+z016zy9vA9r911kTMZHRxAy3QkGSGT2RT+rCpSx4/VBEnkjWNHiDxpg8v+R70rfk/Fla4OndTRQ8Bnc+MUCH7lP59zuDMKz10/NIeWiu5T6CUVAgMBAAGjgbIwga8wDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwbQYIKwYBBQUHAQwEYTBfoV2gWzBZMFcwVRYJaW1hZ2UvZ2lmMCEwHzAHBgUrDgMCGgQUj+XTGoasjY5rw8+AatRIGCx7GS4wJRYjaHR0cDovL2xvZ28udmVyaXNpZ24uY29tL3ZzbG9nby5naWYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFH/TZafC3ey78DAJ80M5+gKvMzEzMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQCTJEowX2LP2BqYLz3q3JktvXf2pXkiOOzEp6B4Eq1iDkVwZMXnl2YtmAl+X6/WzChl8gGqCBpH3vn5fJJaCGkgDdk+bW48DW7Y5gaRQBi5+MHt39tBquCWIMnNZBU4gcmU7qKEKQsTb47bDN0lAtukixlE0kF6BWlKWE9gyn6CagsCqiUXObXbf+eEZSqVir2G3l6BFoMtEMze/aiCKm0oHw0LxOXnGiYZ4fQRbxC1lfznQgUy286dUV4otp6F01vvpX1FQHKOtw5rDgb7MzVIcbidJ4vEZV8NhnacRHr2lVz2XTIIM6RUthg/aFzyQkqFOFSDX9HoLPKsEdao7WNq
MIDlet-Icon: icon.png
MIDlet-Jar-RSA-SHA1: kmm1vudu0LMI/swCctyjPcN+QA/RAo12PCp3yAw8Gia60gzsZ69MYZNjIx8cZraxXnDQ+W2odE/1uTOWkQKwjc+kDRQ2RXwQcchphNVpOcOCeqUkDLk71S7hp8KSuqzCLI46OgRMZ39er1UVKAR9tEZdFvXUDtuOQZPvGr1eQ1qqJZ8l+3EKCGo2XmUzcNG0ACeZv8Ueuh//70/VQ08K2yP4S/0NPUpochrkouYro9HbZZuhL80jIzbmPE9WP1d85d4OcTaq8+YC3+nMAk+Bgs47+brrWser421gEU07RxLOvaxvPKv/Ft4I3QKMacStKHPt1OUCWR+X9VtngqpKrg==
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 1301162
MIDlet-Jar-URL: Hungama.jar
MIDlet-Name: Hungama
MIDlet-Permissions: javax.microedition.io.Connector.http,javax.microedition.io.Connector.socket,javax.wireless.messaging.sms.send,javax.microedition.io.Connector.sms,javax.microedition.io.Connector.file.write,javax.microedition.io.Connector.file.read
MIDlet-Vendor: Hungama Digital Media Entertainment Pvt. Ltd.
MIDlet-Version: 1.0.67
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.0
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.1
Nokia-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad: no
```

Thank you,

Regards,
Datta V.

Comment: even im looking for the answer